# Some smart scopes not working

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

In addition to one of my questions here on this site, I discovered that a lot of my enabled smart scopes do not work in Ubuntu 13.10. For example Zotero, almost all music lenses except banshee etc...

In fact, the only thing that works flawlessly is the local file search lens and the applications lens.

Reinstallation of `unity-scope*` and `unity-lens*` or `rm -rf .local/share/zeitgeist/` doesn't help either...

Is there anything I can do about that, or is it a bug I should report? How does a working smart-scope look like?